# How do we create an empty map and append new data in golang?

Tags: go

I'm having a problem with creating an empty map and append new data to it while looping on another map.

this is the error i'm getting on my IDE.

[image]

here's my data struct to be added to the map.

```
type Outcome struct {
QuestionIndex string
ChoiceIndex   int64
Correct       bool
}

func createEntryOutcome(e *entry.Entry) map[string]interface{} {
entryPicks := e.Live.Picks
outcomes := make(map[string]interface{})
for idx, pick := range entryPicks {
    mappedPick := pick.(map[string]interface{})
    outcomes = append(outcomes, Outcome{
        QuestionIndex: idx,
        ChoiceIndex:   mappedPick["index"].(int64),
        Correct:       mappedPick["correct"].(bool),
    })
}
return outcomes
}
```

i basically want something like below to be saved in the database.

```
[
  {
    qIndex: "1",
    cIndex: 1,
    correct: false,
  },
  {
    qIndex: "1",
    cIndex: 1,
    correct: false,
  },
]
```

im new to golang and any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Since you apparently know the types of your mappedPick entries why are you using interface{} and type-casting everywhere?

Comment: Also you seem to know how a map works since mappedPick is a map. Why try to use append on a map when you already have code using maps correctly?

Comment: Look at the Go tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info especially the language reference bit: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types

Comment: You probably wanted a `Slices` (`[]Outcome`) for the `outcomes` instead of `map[string]interface{}`

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly says:

> first argument to append must be slice; have map[string]interface{}

which means you need to create a slice before appending the data to outcomes which is actually slice of outcomes, like you have mentioned in the output you want.

> The append function appends the elements x to the end of the slice s,
>   and grows the slice if a greater capacity is needed.

Create a slice of `outcomes` and then append the data from `entryPicks` to that slice:

```
outcomes := make([]map[string]interface{})
for idx, pick := range entryPicks {
    mappedPick := pick.(map[string]interface{})
    outcomes = append(outcomes, Outcome{
        QuestionIndex: idx,
        ChoiceIndex:   mappedPick["index"].(int64),
        Correct:       mappedPick["correct"].(bool),
    })
}
```

which will let you provide the outcome you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Outcome struct {
QuestionIndex string
ChoiceIndex   int64
Correct       bool
}

func createEntryOutcome(e *entry.Entry) map[string]interface{} {
entryPicks := e.Live.Picks
var outcomes []Outcome
for idx, pick := range entryPicks {
    mappedPick := pick.(map[string]interface{})
    outcomes = append(outcomes, Outcome{
        QuestionIndex: idx,
        ChoiceIndex:   mappedPick["index"].(int64),
        Correct:       mappedPick["correct"].(bool),
    })
}
return outcomes
}
```

change ***outcomes := make(map[string]interface{})*** to ***var outcomes []Outcome***